# Traditional JSONP: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Tags: javascript, html, jsonp

I have this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.roblox.com/games/getgameinstancesjson?placeId=1818&startindex=0&jsonp=processResults"></script>
    <script>
        function parseResults(results) {
            alert('success');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run this, it comes up with an error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

I've looked this up, but all the solutions were with JQuery. I'm not using JQuery; I'm using the "tranditional" JSONP.

How do I fix this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're going to have to post the contents of the response, because that's where the problem is.

Comment: jsonp and jquery are not really comparable things

Comment: Are you sure it is `parseResults()`. Your JSONP callback is `processResults()`

Answer (score 0):

Try open the `http://www.roblox.com/games/getgameinstancesjson?placeId=1818&startindex=0&jsonp=processResults` link in your browser. As you can see it returns `JSON`, not `JSONP`.

For this to work the result should look like this:

```
processResults({JSON COMES HERE})
```

instead of:

```
{JSON COMES HERE}
```

So I guess you might need to consult the documentation of the server side script to ensure that it returns properly encoded `JSONP` result where the response is wrapped in the callback function you provided.

So if the server doesn't support JSONP or CORS, you might need to write a server side script on your own website that will act as a bridge between your domain and the remote host and then send the AJAX request to your own domain.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this. Could you provide the full code to fix this issue? Thank you in advance.

Comment: There's no way to fix this issue from the client. It's a server side issue. The server must support JSONP. Please read about the JSONP format that the server needs to return: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP. So basically the server should wrap the resulting JSON in a callback that you provide. By looking at the [Wiki of roblox.com](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Web_APIs) they don't seem to support JSONP.

Comment: How do I make sure the server can handle JSON? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You read their documentation. By looking at their [Wiki](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Web_APIs) they don't mention any JSONP, so I guess they do not support it.

Comment: The documentation of the server side script you are trying to consume. In your case that would be `roblox.com`. By googling here's the link I found: http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Web_APIs. They don't seem to mention absolutely anything about JSONP.